# error CS0103: The name 'AssetPreview' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my Unity Project I've C# code to get Prefabs preview image in png format.

In Unity Play mode I have not errors with this Script and everything it's ok, but when I trie to build my project I've receive error.

I spend a lot of times to try understand where I'd made a mistake, but no result.

Can some body help with this problem?

C# Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;
using System;

public class LoadTexture : MonoBehaviour
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class LoadTex
    {
        public string name;
        public GameObject texture;
        public Texture2D gameObjectTex;
        public Texture gameObjTex;
    }

    public List<LoadTex> ItemTablezz = new List<LoadTex>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ItemTablezz.Count; i++)
        {
            var getImage = UnityEditor.AssetPreview.GetAssetPreview(ItemTablezz[i].texture);
            print(getImage);

            ItemTablezz[i].gameObjectTex = getImage;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        CheckIfNull();
    }

    void CheckIfNull()
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < ItemTablezz.Count; k++)
        {
            Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(128, 128, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
            Color[] colors = ItemTablezz[k].gameObjectTex.GetPixels();
            int i = 0;
            Color alpha = colors[i];
            for (; i < colors.Length; i++)
            {
                if (colors[i] == alpha)
                {
                    colors[i].a = 0;
                }
            }

            tex.SetPixels(colors);
            tex.Apply();
            byte[] png = tex.EncodeToPNG();
            File.WriteAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + ItemTablezz[k].name + ".png", png);
        }
    }
}
```

> error CS0103: The name 'AssetPreview' does not exist in the current context

Where I'd made mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UnityEditor.AssetPreview` belongs to the `UnityEditor` namespace.

This only exists in the Unity Editor istelf and is stripped of in a build.

=> You can't use anything fromt the `UnityEditor` namespace in a build.

---

There are basically two solutions in order to exclude `UnityEditor` stuff from builds:

#### Pre-processors

In c# you can use the [`#if preprocessor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) in order to exclude code blocks depending on global defines. Unity offers such [defines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html). In this case use e.g.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    // CODE USING UnityEditor
#endif
```

#### `Editor` folder

If an entire script shall be excluded from a build you can simply place it in a folder named [`Editor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html). This will make it completely stripped of from a build.

---

For using this in a build you would either have to use another library or run this script once within the Unity Editor and store those references for using them in a build e.g. using the [`[ContextMenu]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ContextMenu.html) attribute:

```
    void Start()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        LoadPreviewImages();
#endif

        // if nothing more comes here
        // rather remove this method entirely
        ...
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    // This allows you to call this method 
    // from the according components context menu in the Inspector
    [ContextMenu("LoadPreviewImages")]
    private void LoadPreviewImages()
    {
        foreach (var loadText in ItemTablezz)
        {
            var getImage = UnityEditor.AssetPreview.GetAssetPreview(loadText.texture);
            print(getImage);
            loadText.gameObjectTex = getImage;
        }
    }
#endif
```

Comment: I’ll try your solution later and feed back